# Spark Java Serialization Exception - Task not Serializable

Tags: apache-spark

started on Spark couple of days back. I am not able to find enough info to solve this issue. Reading some records from Cassandra and trying to group it, before doing additional logic.

I am getting Task Not Serializable in this code block. All of the Custom defined entities are Serializable

rdd.cache();

```
        JavaPairRDD<EventStatusGroupKey, Iterable<TestEvent>> groupedRdd = rdd.groupBy(new Function<TestEvent, EventStatusGroupKey>() {
            @Override
            public EventStatusGroupKey call(TestEvent testEvent) throws Exception {
                int minute = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(UUID.fromString(testEvent.getEid()).timestamp()), ZoneId.systemDefault()).getMinute();
                return new EventStatusGroupKey(testEvent.getStatus(), minute);
            }
        });
```

What could be causing this issue ?

Comment: Got it working. It was a simple mistake

Answer (score -1):

are you sure about being serializable objects contained in the custom classes?

Comment: Put your questions for more information in comments. Not as an answer.

Comment: Yes all entities are serializable, and they fields itself are primitives and String. This works perfectly fine while I run it in local mode

Comment: It's obviously true to be run in local mode because there is not one node and there is no need to serialize classes to send them via network to other executors.